# Selenium Python wait for animated element to stop

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium with Python and I have not figured out how to wait for an animated element that moves around the page to stop before clicking on it. For example:

Then next piece of code leads to a page that when clicking on the button 'Aanmeleden' an input box with username and password appears. However, there is a little animation that drags the window from the top.

As expected, next code does not work

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverFile)
driver.get('http://www.collectandgo.be/cogo/nl/home')
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Aanmelden").click()
driver.find_element_by_name("viewLogonid").send_keys('myUser')
```

The next code does not work either

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui

wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverFile)
driver.get('http://www.collectandgo.be/cogo/nl/home')
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Aanmelden").click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'viewLogonid'))).send_keys('myUser')
```

Particularly, the last piece of code gives the next error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (690, 65). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 810px;"></div>\n  (Session info: chrome=34.0.1847.116)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 3.5.0-36-generic x86_64)'
```

I checked the documentation in [Selenium py docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) but I have not found any good workaround.

Comment: What about using `time.sleep(3)` (or whatever an appropriate delay is)?

Comment: that is nice, when you just have to sleep once. But if the animation occurs every single time you move around it can be annoying to pad everything with `time.sleep()`.

Comment: I have the same issue right now. Seems like no one has found a solution to this problem yet, so I might try to create a function for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use JavaScript & jQuery to do this. For example:

```
def wait_for_animation(self, selector):
      is_animation_in_progress = self.is_element_animated(selector)
      while is_animation_in_progress is True:
          sleep(.5)
          is_animation_in_progress = self.is_element_animated(selector)

  def is_element_animated(self, selector):
      return self._driver.execute_script("return jQuery('" + selector + "').is(':animated');")
```

This assumes you can access the element you need with a standard jQuery selector, such as 'div:contains(Aanmelden)'

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made a function that checked if the element was moving by checking its position after certain interval of time but your solution seems much more clearer.